# The use of 会 in 我们每次谈都会吵架

Tags: grammar

In the next sentence what is the meaning of 会.

> 我们每次谈都会吵架。

What is the meaning and difference if you drop out 会.

我们每次谈都会吵架 meaning is:

我们每次谈都吵架 meaning is:

Answer (score 3):

They are same.

```
我们每次谈都会吵架=We quarrel every time we talk
我们每次谈都吵架=We quarrel every time we talk
```

If you just want to say they are different you can see

`我们每次谈都会吵架`as every time we talk will lead to quarrel .

**會**has an emphasis mean.

Answer (score 3):

我们每次谈都会吵架

Every time we may/might talk we ''are going to'' argue / we are sure to argue

More of a conditional feel.

我们每次谈都吵架

Every time we talk, we argue / we do argue / we do indeed argue

More of a habitual feel.

Answer (score 3):

会 simply mean: "would" in this context

我们每次谈都吵架 = every time we talk, we quarrel --> *implies no exception*

我们每次谈都(会)吵架 = every time we talk, we (would) quarrel --> *implies talk inevitably lead to argument*

Answer (score 3):

Both of the sentences have the same meaning.

會 is used to indicate that some situations are positive(do exist). So your sentence 吵架 after 會 is some situation that do exit.

都 is used to indicate that some situations are always positive(do exist). So situation in your sentences 会吵架, 吵架 will be exist in the given condition(我们每次谈).

So 都會 is show that some situations are always positive(do exist).

If you want to express that there is probability for some situations to occur, you can use 有可能會。For example, 喝完這500毫升的水，你有可能會覺得脹脹的。(You have probability to feel bloated after drink this 500ml water.)

Answer (score 1):

'every time we talk' means you start off just talking, otherwise write:

我们总是吵架。

so I would translate:

我们每次谈都会吵架。
Every time we talk, we end up arguing.